# Automatically have Chrome quit or restart when plugin crashes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Does anyone know if it is possible to have Chrome quit or restart automatically when a plugin crashes? It now simply displays the message that the plugin has crashed and everything stops there.

Comment: Depending on how much control you have over the plugin, you might be able to write something in JavaScript. Can you tell us more about the use case?

Comment: Why would you want to restart the browser when you could just reload the tab?

Comment: Is the plugin that keeps crashing the _horrid_ Pepper Flash player?    Along with the problem that that plugin crashes all the time is the problem that a single copy runs in the main chrome process (rather than a copy per tab.)  (Its type is "PPAPI(out-of-process)".)  If that's the problem the solution is: go to Adobe, download the "real" Flash player, install _that_ plugin in Chrome, then go into chrome://plugins and disable the PepperFlash plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, all. The plugin it concerns is the VLC Web Plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way (besides requesting a feature like you already did) is to build chromium yourself from source and modify the [SadTabController](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/tab_contents/sad_tab_controller.mm&q=SadTabController&sq=package:chromium&l=28&type=cs) to call [RequestRestart](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/restart_browser.h&q=restar&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=14) as soon as it is initialized, you can also keep a process running and polling the screen searching for the crash images/text/background color (Sikuli is great for this).

The only other options I see is using another browser or setting up a task to restart the browser periodically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option for Chrome. You must restart the browser manually or for some plugins you can refresh the page to make the plugin run again. For Chromium you might try the suggestion from @RuntimeError

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the program yourselves. it can be achieved by launching this from command line on regular interval:

```
Chrome.exe "data/text:html,ready"
Chrome.exe "javascript: IF {try plugin.function()} catch error {send jms message to some receiver}
```

On the outside, Java JMS listener, invoke

```
taskkill /F "imagename eq chrome.exe"
Chrome.exe "url"
```

I didn't post the details here, but you should be able to do it with some time, just to remind you that the Javascript has length limits of around 1000 characters due to both the command line's and also Chrome's address bar limits.